# How do I turn this model into a materialized view in sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, materialized-views, sequelize-typescript

I have a model which currently creates a table. I would like to turn this into a materialized view instead. How can I do this?

```
/* eslint import/no-cycle: "off" */
import {
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Column,
  Table,
  Min,
  AllowNull,
  AutoIncrement,
  BelongsTo,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { FeedItem } from 'data/models';
 
@Table({
  freezeTableName: true,
})
export default class FeedItemLikesDislikesAggregate extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  feedItemLikesDislikesAggregateId: number;
 
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Min(0)
  @Column
  dislikes: number;
 
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Min(0)
  @Column
  likes: number;
 
  @BelongsTo(() => FeedItem, {
    foreignKey: { name: 'feedItemId', allowNull: false },
    as: 'feedItemId_',
  })
  feedItemId: FeedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done it using [sequelize.query](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/)

First you would create a MATERIALIZED VIEW

```
// somewhere along your migrations/sync method

sequelize.query (`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS FeedItemLikesDislikesAggregateMV  AS
               SELECT   whatever, you, want, to
               FROM     FeedItemLikesDislikesAggregate
               GROUP BY 1;`);
```

I guess you could create a model for that without the fields and use it as a normal sequelize **Model** like your class above: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/legacy/

```
FeedItemLikesDislikesAggregateMV.findAll();
```

However, I have used `sequelize.query` again here:

```
export const FILDAMV = sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM FeedItemLikesDislikesAggregateMV`);
```

And you can always refresh it by doing:

```
sequelize.query(`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW unique_words;`);
```

If that sounds too complicated/problematic you could use this library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-mv-support

I haven't used it myself. But if it suits you, then that's fine. Good luck.